# Concatenate variable horizontally to make one variable in matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, concatenation

Is it possible to concatenate multiple variable horizontally to make a single variable in Matlab?

For Example, I want to join:

```
year = 2001, month = 06, day = 15
```

to make one variable `'20010615'` which I could search in a matrix.

I hope I am clear.

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a string output, use string formatting and `sprintf`

```
sprintf('%04d%02d%02d', year, month, day );
```

If you want a numeric output, simply multiply

```
day + 100 * month + 10000 * year
```

#### Update:

Thanks to [@Joshua's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687666/concatenate-variable-horizontally-to-make-one-variable-in-matlab/16687709?noredirect=1#comment24018293_16687709): if you are indeed working with date/time information you should also look into `datestr` that allows more speciallized formatting for date and time information.

Comment: No glory for seconds in the [tag:matlab] race!

Comment: If you're interested in date strings specifically, [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) is the best tool for the job. E.g. it allows localization.